# Proving a property on Hilbert-Schmidt operator 's norm.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $E\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and with $|E|>0$ (positive measure), we know $L^2(E)$ is a Hilbert space; so, given $K\in L^2(E\times E)$, we can define the Hilbert-Schmidt operator
$$T_K:L^2(E) \to L^2(E)$$
such that, $\forall f\in L^2(E)$,
$$(T_Kf)(x) := \int_E K(x,y) f(y) dy.$$

Since $L^2(E)$ is a Hilbert space, you can use Schwarts' inequality to determine that $\Vert T_k \Vert_{\mathcal{L}(L^2(E))} \le \Vert K\Vert_{L^2(E\times E)}$, in fact
$$\Vert T_Kf \Vert_{L^2(E)}^2 =\int_E \Bigg( \int_E k(x,y) f(y) dy \Bigg)^2 dx \le \int_E \Bigg( \int_E \big(K(x,y)\big)^2dy \cdot \int_E \big(f(y)\big)^2 dy \Bigg) dx =$$
$$= \int_{E\times E} \big(K(x,y)\big)^2 dxdy \cdot \Vert f \Vert_2^2 = \Vert K \Vert_{L^2(E\times E)}^2 \cdot \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(E)}^2,$$
so that, by definition of norm of an operator, we get that inequality.

**My request**: does somebody know how to prove that actually equality holds; in other words that, with the generality of the Hilbert-Schmidt operators, we always have
$$\Vert T_k \Vert_{\mathcal{L}(L^2(E))} = \Vert K\Vert_{L^2(E\times E)} .$$

---

I am not sure that this is true, but in particular cases I seem to be able to show that equality holds and, if not, I can never show that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the $L^2$-norm of $K$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $T_K$. You are looking for the operator norm of $T_K$, which is usually smaller. In matrices, if you have
$$
K=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
then $\|K\|_2=\sqrt5$, while $\|K\|=2$. Below is an adaptation of this idea to your context.

Write $E=E_1\cup E_2$ with $E_1\cap E_2=\emptyset$ and $|E_1|=|E_2|=|E|/2$.  Let
$$
K(x,y)=1^\vphantom{E}_{E_1\times E_1}+2\,1^\vphantom{E}_{E_2\times E_2}. 
$$
So
$$
T_Kf(x)=\Big(\int_{E_1}f\Big)\,1^\vphantom{E}_{E_1}+2\,\Big(\int_{E_2}f\Big)\,1^\vphantom E_{E_2}.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\|T_kf\|_2^2&=\Big|\int_{E_1}f\Big|^2\,|E_1|+4\,\Big|\int_{E_2}f\Big|^2\,|E_2|
\leq |E_1|^2\,\int_{E_1}|f|^2+4|E_2|^2\,\int_{E_2}|f|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{|E|^2}4\,\bigg[\int_{E_1}|f|^2+4\int_{E_2}|f|^2\bigg]
=\frac{|E|^2}4\,\bigg[4\|f\|^2_2-3\int_{E_1}|f|^2\bigg]\\[0.3cm]
&\leq |E|^2\,\|f\|_2^2.
\end{align}
The equality is achieved when $f=\frac{\sqrt2}{|E|^{1/2}}\,\,1_{E_2}$. Thus $\|T_K\|=|E|$.

Meanwhile,
$$
\|K\|_2^2=\int_E\int_E |K(x,y)|^2\,dy\,dx
=\int_{E\times E}1_{E_1\times E_1}+4\int_{E\times E}1_{E_2\times E_2}
=|E_1|^2+4|E_2|^2=\frac{5|E|^2}4.
$$
That is,
$$
\|K\|_2^2=\frac{\sqrt5\,|E|}2>|E|=\|T_K\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I had some trouble at the beginning, but it all seems appropriate. There are limitations to put on $E$, for this process to work, in particular it has to have finite measure and, also, $E$ must be "divisible" just as you claimed (right?) this however is possible because for example the unit ball has this property (can be divided in two semispheres where only one contains the middle boundary). Now for curiosity's sake: is this always possible?

Comment: I think it is standard that in any diffuse measure space (no atoms) a set with positive measure has subsets of any measure ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures)).  When $|E|=\infty$, one can still do the same example by choosing disjoint $E_1$,$E_2$ with $|E_1|=|E_2|$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. For the $|E|=\infty$ case, already $\Vert T_kf\Vert_2^2=\Big|\int_{E_1}f\Big|^2|E_1|+4\Big|\int_{E_2}f\Big|^2|E_2|$ written this way shows that $\|T_kf\|_2^2=+\infty$, so one cannot deduce what you have done.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean you can anyways choose $E_1, E_2 \subseteq E$ such that $|E_1|=|E_2|<+\infty$.

Comment: Yes. In matrices, I'm saying that you can always put $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ as the top left corner of an operator on infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.